# knockout.js reusable templates with foreach

Tags: templates, foreach, knockout.js

I have this template

```
<!--ko template: { name: 'multiCheckBtn', data: { elems: posGenders, compareWith: gender, switch: switchCheckBtn} }-->
<!--/ko-->

<script id="multiCheckBtn" type="text/html">
  <span class="fakeCheck" data-bind="foreach: { data: $data.elems, as: 't' } ">
    // here $data becomes alias to t and I don't how to access other params, like $data.switch
    <span class="btn" data-bind="text: t, css: { selected: t == $data.compareWith() }, click: $data.switch } "></span>
  </span>
</script>
```

What I want is inside `foreach` to get access to `compareWith` and `switch` variables passed to template originally, but I only can access them before `foreach`. Inside loop `$data` variable becomes alias to `t`, and I can't access other variables.

Is there a way how I can pass the data to `foreach` loop, so that I could access it like I'm trying to access in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them using `$parent` object:

```
<script id="multiCheckBtn" type="text/html">
  <span class="fakeCheck" data-bind="foreach: { data: $data.elems, as: 't' } ">
    <span class="btn" data-bind="text: t, css: { selected: t == $parent.compareWith() }, click: $parent.switch } "></span>
  </span>
</script>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/nVsgK/

Comment: I can assure you I tried so many variations, even `$parent.$data.switch`, but never occurred to try the one you wrote.
Thanks